# C++ run threads on different cores

Tags: c++, multithreading

If i have 2 cores in my processor, and i want to start 4 threads. Is it possible to run 2 threads on 1st core, and 2 another threads on 2nd core(Using c++11, without boost, os Linux). Or os will do it for me? Thank you.

Comment: The OS scheduler will take care of that. As far as I know, all you can do is to limit which CPUs to use. More over, same threads can operate in different CPUs along time.

Comment: yes you can use more than one thread on a single core.  Operating system can decide on scheduling time based on its policy

Answer (score 1):

There's no ability to choose processor cores in standard C++, nor is there generally a need to do so. The OS will pick cores for your threads.

Keep in mind that you can't even rely on the number of cores being constant. A laptop or mobile phone may power on and off cores on demand. What if the cores you picked were powered off?

Comment: However, on Linux, there is [sched_setaffinity(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html)

Comment: On Windows there is [SetThreadAffinityMask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686247(v=vs.85).aspx)